# What regions do Yukhari, Yukhari Karabakh, Upper Karabakh, and Nagorno Karabakh refer to, respectively?

Tags: azerbaijan

I found sources referring to [Yukhari](http://www.statoids.com/uaz.html), to the [Yukhari-Karabakh Economic Region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_Karabakh_Economic_Region), the [Upper Karabakh Economic Region](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukhari-Karabakh_economic_region), and to [Nagorno-Karabakh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagorno-Karabakh). The terms Yukhari, Yukhari-Karabakh, Upper Karabakh, and Nagorno-Karabakh seem to be closely related. I'm curious as to what place each of them is referring to.

Also, as a bonus, what is the appropriate ISO 3166-2 code for each (if they are different) or all of these places?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly Yukhari (or Yuxarı, in this answer I'm going to use the conventional English spelling of Azeri words) is just the Azeri word for "Upper". So there is no difference between "Yukhari-Karabakh" and "Upper-Karabakh"

[image]
Nagorno-Karabakh is the ethnically mostly Armenian region in Green It was a former Oblast in the Soviet Union. It is not currently a defined administrative region of Azerbaijan.

Upper Karabakh is one of the 11 economic regions of Azerbaijan.  It is composed of the districts of

- Aghdam
- Fuzuli
- Jabrayil
- Khojaly
- Khojavend
- Shusha
- Tartar
- Khankendi
- Shusha

That is the area of Nagorno-Karabakh plus the predominantly Azeri districts of Agdam, Jabrayil and Fizuli.

The actual control of the area has shifted.  After the first Nagorno-Karabakh war, Azerbaijan lost control of the area to Armenia. In the second war (in 2020) Azerbaijan forces regained control of some of the areas previously under Armenian control.

ISO codes haven't been assigned at the "economic region" level, but at the district level, so Tartar is AZ-TAR, and [others can be found from  wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:AZ)

<sub>map by Wikipedia user Golbez. Own work., CC BY 2.5, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=479872</sub>

Answer (score 6):

There are three geopolitical entities here:

1. An "autonomous region" that existed in times of Soviet occupation;
2. An economic region of Azerbaijan;
3. A territory held by Armenian armed forces (1994-2020).

---

| Map | Description | Names |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Nagorno-Karabakh Autonomous Oblast] | [Nagorno-Karabakh Autonomous Oblast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagorno-Karabakh_Autonomous_Oblast) of the USSR was established as a region of "Azerbaijani Soviet Socialist Republic". Included 5 districts ("raions"): Askeran, Hadrut, Mardakert, Martuni, Shusha | - Нагорный Карабах /Nagornyj Karabax/ (Russian) - Nagorno-Karabakh Autonomous Oblast (semi-accurate romanization from Russian) - NKAO (the abbreviation) |
| [image: Upper Karabakh] | [Upper Karabakh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_divisions_of_Azerbaijan#Economic_Regions), an economic region of Azerbaijan (colored brown on the map). Includes 8 districts: Aghdam, Fuzuli, Jabrayil, Khankendi, Khojaly, Khojavend, Shusha, Tartar. | - Yuxarı Qarabağ (Azerbaijani) - Yukhari-Karabakh Economic Region (romanization) - Yukhari (a contraction of the above) - Upper Karabakh Economic Region (translation to English) |
| [image: Armenia-controlled territory] | [Factually Armenia-controlled territory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagorno-Karabakh_Line_of_Contact) (1994-2020), self-proclaimed [Republic of Artsakh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_Artsakh) | - Արցախի Հանրապետություն (Armenian) - Artsakhi Hanrapetutyun (romanized from Armenian) - Нагорно-Карабахская Республика (Russian) - Nagorno-Karabakhskaya Respublika (romanized from Russian) |

Comment: A lot of territory is still being held by Armenia.